# How to hide li and label without class or ID or sharing global class/ID

Tags: css

I'm trying to hide li and label from a page.

My problem is the li doesn't have any specific ID or class.
the same with the label.

```
<li><a href="https://www.test.com/feature/%d8%ac%d9%85%d8%b9-%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%a7%d9%86%d9%85%d8%a7%d8%b7/"><i class="fa fa-check"></i>this is label text</a></li>
```

And this is the second one

```
<label class="checkbox-inline"><input name="feature[]" type="checkbox" value="%d8%ac%d9%85%d8%b9-%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%a7%d9%86%d9%85%d8%a7%d8%b7">جمع الانماط</label>
```

Is there any trick to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

```
:not([class]):not([id]) {display: none; }
```

Comment: But for example label class="checkbox-inline" the class is global, there is 20 label share the same class in the same page

Comment: As an option, you could add `:not([class="checkbox-inline"])` for each of classes. But it’s generally easier and potentially more performant to add a class to target elements, and target that class instead of multiple `:not()`s.

Comment: Oh, `:not(.checkbox-inline)` would be more universal than `:not([class="checkbox-inline"])` and would work if the element has multiple classes.